# Is there a way to get old revisions of Apple Sample Code?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

For example, I would like to see the pre-Leopard API version of [HID Explorer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/HID_Explorer/Introduction/Intro.html).  I see in the revision history that the initial sample was created on 2003-01-14.  Is there any way to get that revision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no. Unless you have an older system restore disc (they came with older versions of Xcode and I think the documentation came with them) or one of the older ADC DVD mailings that went away in favor of online downloads.

Comment: Apple still has old Xcode downloads on their website. Use connect.apple.com to log in (a free account will work) and choose the Developer Tools section. I believe every version comes with some samples, its just sometimes hard to find and not all of the samples are included.

Comment: You should've made that an answer! I would've up-voted you. :-) To specify, you have to go to Developer Downloads -> Developer Tools. Everything back through Xcode 2.x is there. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Here are links to all the old Xcode downloads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file and doc sets:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542614/download-xcode-4-2-documentation-for-offline-install/8542901#8542901

Answer (score 1):

You can access older code samples through an older "documentation set". Documentation samples may have been bundled with Xcode in the past, but this is no longer the case. Downloading an older version of Xcode may be a waste, depending on how far back you want to go.

If you look at the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8542901/867760) it will show you how to download an older documentation set. Xcode uses an ATOM feed to download / update documentation sets, so it's just a matter of adding the correct URL.

After downloading the documentation set you can search/view both versions in `Window -> Organizer -> Documentation`.

(In my case I wanted the older version of `PhotoScroller`. Since iOS 6.0, they changed the slider from a dequeing `UIScrollView` to a `UIPageViewController`).